# Binomial Theorem. Can this be proved or not .

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

Is is possible to prove that

$${10 \choose 1 } + {10 \choose 3} + {10 \choose 5} + {10 \choose 7} + {10 \choose 9} ={2^{10-1}}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $\;10_{c_i}\;$ ??

Comment: Oh, rats! Again, I'd love to be mind reader.

Comment: Bad formatted *and* a duplicate. Notice that: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k = 0,\qquad \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} = 2^n. $$ Consider half the difference and plug in $n=10$.

Comment: For the particular case $n=10$, an explicit numerical computation does it: a computation is a proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the Binomial Theorem
$$
\begin{align}
&(1+1)^{10}\\
&=\small\binom{10}{0}+\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{4}+\binom{10}{5}+\binom{10}{6}+\binom{10}{7}+\binom{10}{8}+\binom{10}{9}+\binom{10}{10}\\
&(1-1)^{10}\\
&=\small\binom{10}{0}-\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{2}-\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{4}-\binom{10}{5}+\binom{10}{6}-\binom{10}{7}+\binom{10}{8}-\binom{10}{9}+\binom{10}{10}
\end{align}
$$
Add and divide by $2$:
$$
2^9=\binom{10}{0}+\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{4}+\binom{10}{6}+\binom{10}{8}+\binom{10}{10}
$$
Subtract and divide by $2$:
$$
2^9=\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{5}+\binom{10}{7}+\binom{10}{9}
$$